# Using count_all_results or get_compiled_select and $this->db->get('table') lists table twice in query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How do I use get_compiled_select or count_all_results before running the query without getting the table name added twice?  When I use $this->db->get('tblName') after either of those, I get the error:

```
Not unique table/alias: 'tblProgram'

SELECT * FROM (`tblProgram`, `tblProgram`) JOIN `tblPlots` ON `tblPlots`.`programID`=`tblProgram`.`pkProgramID` JOIN `tblTrees` ON `tblTrees`.`treePlotID`=`tblPlots`.`id` ORDER BY `tblTrees`.`id` ASC LIMIT 2000
```

If I don't use a table name in count_all_results or $this->db->get(), then I get an error that no table is used.  How can I get it to set the table name just once?

```
public function get_download_tree_data($options=array(), $rand=""){

//join tables and order by tree id
   $this->db->reset_query();
   $this->db->join('tblPlots','tblPlots.programID=tblProgram.pkProgramID');
   $this->db->join('tblTrees','tblTrees.treePlotID=tblPlots.id');
   $this->db->order_by('tblTrees.id', 'ASC');

//get number of results to return
   $allResults=$this->db->count_all_results('tblProgram', false);

//chunk data and write to CSV to avoid reaching memory limit
   $offset=0;
   $chunk=2000;
   $treePath=$this->config->item('temp_path')."$rand/trees.csv";
   $tree_handle=fopen($treePath,'a');
   while (($offset<$allResults)) {
      $this->db->limit($chunk, $offset);  
      $result=$this->db->get('tblProgram')->result_array();
      foreach ($result as $row) {
           fputcsv($tree_handle, $row);
      }    
      $offset=$offset+$chunk;
    }
                    
    fclose($tree_handle);
    return array('resultCount'=>$allResults);
 }
```

Comment: I have written an answer to your question. Unfortunately I'm not particularly knowledgable about CodeIgniter, so I only outlined the idea that you need to apply, but I did not implement a full solution. Nevertheless, please let me know of the results while you try applying it. Also, if you could tell me on which line is your code failing, that would be great. Is the code failing at `$allResults=$this->db->count_all_results('tblProgram', false);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rick James got me on the right track.  I ended up having to chunk the results using pagination AND a nested query.  Using LIMIT on even 1 chunk of 2000 records was timing out.  This is the code I ended up with, which uses get_compiled_select('tblProgram') and then get('tblTrees O1').  Since I didn't use FALSE as the second argument to get_compiled_select, the query was cleared before the get() was run.

```
        //grab the data in chunks, write it to CSV chunk by chunk
        $offset=0;
        $chunk=2000;    
        $i=10;  //counter for the progress bar
        
        $this->db->limit($chunk);
        $this->db->select('tblTrees.id');
        
        //nesting the limited query and then joining the other field later improved performance significantly
        $query1=' ('.$this->db->get_compiled_select('tblProgram').') AS O2';
        $this->db->join($query1, 'O1.id=O2.id');
       
        $result=$this->db->get('tblTrees O1')->result_array();
        $allResults=count($result);
        $putHeaders=0;
        
        $treePath=$this->config->item('temp_path')."$rand/trees.csv";
        $tree_handle=fopen($treePath,'a');  
        
        //while select limit returns the limit
        while (count($result)===$chunk) {
            $highestID=max(array_column($result, 'id'));
            
            //update progres bar with estimate
            if ($i<90) {
              $this->set_runStatus($qcRunId, $status = "processing", $progress = $i);
              $i=$i+1;
            }

            //only get the fields the first time
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                if ($offset===0 && $putHeaders===0){
                    fputcsv($tree_handle, array_keys($row));
                    $putHeaders=1;
                }
                fputcsv($tree_handle, $row);
            }  
            
            //get the next chunk
            $offset=$offset+$chunk;
            $this->db->reset_query();
            $this->make_query($options);
            $this->db->order_by('tblTrees.id', 'ASC');
            $this->db->where('tblTrees.id >', $highestID);
            $this->db->limit($chunk);
            $this->db->select('tblTrees.id');
            $query1=' ('.$this->db->get_compiled_select('tblProgram').') AS O2';
            $this->db->join($query1, 'O1.id=O2.id');
                   
            $result=$this->db->get('tblTrees O1')->result_array();
            
            $allResults=$allResults+count($result);
        }
            //write out last chunk 
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                fputcsv($tree_handle, $row);
            }          
            fclose($tree_handle);

            return array('resultCount'=>$allResults);
```

Answer (score 3):

To count how many rows *would be* returned by a query, essentially all the work must be performed.  That is, it is impractical to get the count, then perform the query; you may as well just do the query.

If your goal is to "paginate" by getting some of the rows, plus the total count, that is essentially two separate actions (that may be combined to look like one.)

If the goal is to *estimate* the number of rows, then `SHOW TABLE STATUS` or `SELECT` Rows `FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE ...` gives you an *estimate*.

If you want to see if there are, say "at least 100 rows", then this may be practical:

```
SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 99,1
```

and see if you get a row back.  However, this may *or may not* be efficient, depending on the indexes and the `WHERE` and the `ORDER BY`.  (Show us the query and I can elaborate.)

Using `OFFSET` for chunking is grossly inefficient.  If there is not a usable index, then it is performing essentially the entire query for each chunk.  If there is a usable index, the chunks are slower and slower.  Here is a discussion of why `OFFSET` is not good for "pagination", plus an efficient workaround: [*Pagination*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) .  It talks about how to "remember where you left off " as an efficient technique for chunking.  Fetch between 100 and 1000 rows per chunk.

Comment: Thank you!  I want to get all of the data to write to CSV but I was running into a memory limit, so I was trying to chunk the query.  The pagination link you gave is broken for me

Comment: @xanabobana - Sorry.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination  (lower case "p")  The "remember where you left off " is an efficient technique for chunking.  Fetch between 100 and 1000 rows per chunk.

Comment: ARRRRRGH I'm running into the same problem with this solution but with get_compiled_select.  My query is generated in a few different methods (I used the join statements above to approximate, but there are quite a few filters from the front end that are passed).  If I want to loop through and execute my query with different limit I need to be able to save the query so I can change the limit.  But when I use get_compiled_select('myTable', FALSE), it adds the table name twice in the select statement just like count_all_results does.  So I'm still running into the same codeigniter issue :(

Comment: @xanabobana - I can help with the generated SQL, but not with codeigniter.  (Frameworks sometimes make life difficult, especially when trying to get performance out of MySQL.)

Answer (score 2):

The flaw in your code is that it aims to select a subset of some records and their total count in the same query. This is impossible in MySQL, so you cannot generate such a query, hence, you get the error as mentioned. The problem is that if you do a

```
select ... from t where ... limit 0, 2000
```

then you get maximum 2000 records, so, if the total records matching the criteria have a count that is greater than the limit, then you will not get accurately the count from above, so, in that case you need a

```
select count(1) from t where ...
```

This means that you need to build your actual query (the code below your `count_all_results` call), see whether the number of results reaches the limit. If the number of results does not reach the limit, then you do not need to perform a separate query in order to get the count, because you can compute `$offset * $chunk + $recordCount`. However, if you get as many records as they can be, then you will need to build another query, without the `order_by` call, since the count is independent of your sort and get the counts.

Answer (score 0):

**$this->db->count_all_results()**

Counting the number of returned results with `count_all_results()`

It's useful to count the number of results returned—often bugs can arise if a section of code which expects to have at least one row is passed zero rows. Without handling the eventuality of a zero result, an application may become unpredictably unstable and may give away hints to a malicious user about the architecture of the app. Ensuring correct handling of zero results is what we're going to focus on here.

Permits you to determine the number of rows in a particular Active Record query. Queries will accept Query Builder restrictors such as where(), or_where(), like(), or_like(), etc. Example:

```
echo $this->db->count_all_results('my_table');  // Produces an integer, like 25
$this->db->like('title', 'match');
$this->db->from('my_table');
echo $this->db->count_all_results(); // Produces an integer, like 17
```

However, this method also resets any field values that you may have passed to select(). If you need to keep them, you can pass FALSE as the second parameter:

```
echo $this->db->count_all_results('my_table', FALSE);
```

**get_compiled_select()**

The method `$this->db->get_compiled_select();` is introduced in codeigniter v3.0 and compiles active records query without actually executing it. But this is not a completely new method. In older versions of CI it is like `$this->db->_compile_select();` but the method has been made protected in later versions making it impossible to call back.

```
// Note that the second parameter of the get_compiled_select method is FALSE
$sql = $this->db->select(array('field1','field2'))
                                ->where('field3',5)
                                ->get_compiled_select('mytable', FALSE);

// ...
// Do something crazy with the SQL code... like add it to a cron script for
// later execution or something...
// ...

$data = $this->db->get()->result_array();

// Would execute and return an array of results of the following query:
// SELECT field1, field1 from mytable where field3 = 5;
```

**NOTE:-** Double calls to `get_compiled_select()` while you’re using the Query Builder Caching functionality and NOT resetting your queries will results in the cache being merged twice. That in turn will i.e. if you’re caching a select() - select the same field twice.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is helpful...I'm using FALSE as the second argument

Comment: This is very helpful and I am covered about these 2 methods  how it works.If you Know that the working after that you will use these methods.